# BizTalk 2016 Install fails on group creation

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I've tried following the directions for a stand along BizTalk install on multiple Windows 10 machines, but it always fails on group creation.  I've run the BizTalk 2016 Configuration as administrator as well.  Firewall is completely off and SQL Server 2016 is loaded locally on the machine.

Any thoughts as to how to get around this?

```
[2018-07-18 20:34:44:0275 Info RulesEngine] The specified Rules Engine database is compatible with the current version.
[2018-07-18 20:34:44:0285 Info RulesEngine] Leaving function ValidateFeature
[2018-07-18 20:34:44:0311  Info BAMConfigWizExt] Entering function: CBAMConfigWizExt::ValidateFeature
[2018-07-18 20:34:44:0325  Info BAMConfigWizExt] Validating feature: MOT
[2018-07-18 20:34:44:0336  Info BAMConfigWizExt] Leaving function: CBAMConfigWizExt::ValidateFeature
[2018-07-18 20:34:44:0346 Info Configuration Framework]*** Ending Final validation pass. ***
[2018-07-18 20:34:44:0354 Info Configuration Framework]Leaving function ValidateFeatures().
[2018-07-18 20:34:44:0362 Info Configuration Framework][ManualForm_Configuration] thread started.
[2018-07-18 20:34:44:0434 Info Configuration Framework]Entering function ConfigWizardFrame_Load.
[2018-07-18 20:34:44:0450 Info Configuration Framework]Configuration Wizard Mode: 0.
[2018-07-18 20:34:44:0624 Info Configuration Framework]Entering function ConfigWizardSummary_Load.
[2018-07-18 20:34:44:0686 Info Configuration Framework]Leaving function ConfigWizardSummary_Load.
[2018-07-18 20:34:44:0743 Info Configuration Framework]Leaving function ConfigWizardFrame_Load.
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0433 Info Configuration Framework]Entering function WizardStep_NextStepChanged.
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0479 Info Configuration Framework]Leaving function WizardStep_NextStepChanged.
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0480 Info Configuration Framework]Entering function ConfigureFeatures().
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0500 Info Configuration Framework]<Configuration><Feature Name="SSOServer,Engine" DisplayName="Enterprise Single Sign-On" Version="1.0" Description="Enterprise Single Sign-On configuration" ConfigByDefault="true"><Question ID="IsSecretServer" Text="&amp;Create a new SSO system;&amp;Join an existing SSO system" Answers="Create,Join" Default="Create"><Answer Value="Create" GUID="{FB7268BE-82D4-4cad-8CFF-6930303DA7E2}" Selected="Yes"><NTCredential ID="SSOAdminGroup" DisplayName="SSO Administrator(s)" Description="This is the Administrator of the Enterprise Single Sign-On (SSO) system."><NTAccount ScopeType="105" UpLevelFlags="672" DownLevelFlags="2147516422">SSO Administrators</NTAccount></NTCredential><NTCredential ID="SSOAffiliateAdminGroup" DisplayName="SSO Affiliate Administrator(s)" Description="The SSO Affiliate Administrator must be able to create Affiliate Applications."><NTAccount ScopeType="105" UpLevelFlags="672" DownLevelFlags="2147516422">SSO Affiliate Administrators</NTAccount></NTCredential><FILE ID="SSO_ID_BACKUP_SECRET_FILE" DisplayName="&amp;Backup file location:" Filter="Backup files (*.bak)|*.bak|All files (*.*)|*.*" DefaultExtension="bak" Title="" Description="Location where the master secret will be backed up" OpenFile="true"><Value /></FILE><Name ID="SSO_ID_BACKUP_SECRET_PASSWORD" DisplayName="&amp;Secret backup password:" Description="Enter a password used to protect the secret backup file" Hidden="true"><Value></Value></Name><Name ID="SSO_ID_BACKUP_SECRET_PASSWORD_CONFIRM" DisplayName="&amp;Confirm password:" Description="Confirm the secret backup password" Hidden="true"><Value></Value></Name><Name ID="SSO_ID_BACKUP_SECRET_REMINDER" DisplayName="Password &amp;reminder:" Description="Enter a phrase to help you remember the secret backup file password" Hidden="false"><Value /></Name></Answer><Answer Value="Join" GUID="{B9432756-1620-4bec-8CD9-E6D0B7805AA5}" /></Question><NTService ID="ENTSSO" DisplayName="Enterprise Single Sign-On Service" Description="Specify the name of the account under which the Single Sign-On (SSO) service should run. This account must be a member of the SSO Administrator(s) group."><UserName>Stephen</UserName><Domain>.</Domain><Password /></NTService><SQL ID="SSO_DB_ID" DisplayName="SSO Database" Description="Specify the name of the SQL Server and Database that will be used as the credential store."><Server>IHA-STEPHEN</Server><Database>SSODB</Database><WindowsSecurity Editable="no">yes</WindowsSecurity><UserName /><Password /></SQL></Feature><Feature Name="WMI" DisplayName="BizTalk Server Group" Version="1.0" Description="The Microsoft Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) layer encapsulates all administrative functions and management capabilities for BizTalk Server." ConfigByDefault="true" ISDIRTY="true"><SQL ID="{D757DBF9-5D71-4995-9F20-A552B7DFE7F1}" DisplayName="BizTalk Management Database" Description="This database is the central meta-information store for all BizTalk Servers."><Server>IHA-STEPHEN</Server><Database>BizTalkMgmtDb</Database><WindowsSecurity Editable="no">yes</WindowsSecurity><UserName /><Password /></SQL><Question ID="CREATEORJOIN" Text="Create a &amp;new BizTalk Group;&amp;Join an existing BizTalk Group" Answers="Create,Join" Default="Create"><Answer Value="Create" GUID="{C4DEF4B8-163E-4a8d-AB01-6C43917248B1}" Selected="Yes"><SQL ID="{84ADD76E-EBEB-4bb8-B9EB-64F87E483C39}" DisplayName="BizTalk MessageBox Database" Description="This database stores subscriptions predicates. It is a host platform, where the queues and state tables for each BizTalk Server host are kept. The MessageBox database also stores the messages and message properties."><Server>IHA-STEPHEN</Server><Database>BizTalkMsgBoxDb</Database><WindowsSecurity Editable="no">yes</WindowsSecurity><UserName /><Password /></SQL><SQL ID="{1033195A-3C23-4750-BBD0-06BC12A175D4}" DisplayName="BizTalk Tracking Database" Description="This database stores business and health monitoring data tracked by the BizTalk Server tracking engine."><Server>IHA-STEPHEN</Server><Database>BizTalkDTADb</Database><WindowsSecurity Editable="no">yes</WindowsSecurity><UserName /><Password /></SQL><NTCredential ID="BTS_ADMIN_GROUP" DisplayName="BizTalk Administrators Group" Description="The BizTalk Server Administrators Group has the least privileges necessary to perform administrative tasks included in the Configuration Framework Wizard and to administer the BizTalk Server environment after installation."><NTAccount ScopeType="105" UpLevelFlags="672" DownLevelFlags="2147483654">BizTalk Server Administrators</NTAccount></NTCredential><NTCredential ID="BTS_OPERATOR_GROUP" DisplayName="BizTalk Operators Group" Description="The BizTalk Server Operators Group has the least privileges necessary to perform tasks required for operating the BizTalk Server environment after installation."><NTAccount ScopeType="105" UpLevelFlags="672" DownLevelFlags="2147483654">BizTalk Server Operators</NTAccount></NTCredential><NTCredential ID="BTS_B2B_OPERATOR_GROUP" DisplayName="BizTalk B2B Operators Group" Description="The BizTalk Server B2B Operators Group has the least privileges necessary to perform tasks required for operating the BizTalk Server B2B environment after installation."><NTAccount ScopeType="105" UpLevelFlags="672" DownLevelFlags="2147483654">BizTalk Server B2B Operators</NTAccount></NTCredential></Answer><Answer Value="Join" GUID="{4D12E6A3-552E-4936-9DD3-59E1190FA324}" /></Question></Feature><Feature Name="MOT" DisplayName="BAM runtime" Version="1.0" Description="Tracking data decoding service used to move tracked data and persist it for query use." /><Feature Name="RulesEngine" DisplayName="Business Rules Engine" Version="3.0" Description="BizTalk native support for declarative Business Rules." ConfigByDefault="true"><SQL ID="{E6C5E071-D6EB-4c31-BFE6-CA16637FBEEB}" DisplayName="Rule Engine Database" Description="SQL Rule Store"><Server>IHA-STEPHEN</Server><Database>BizTalkRuleEngineDb</Database><WindowsSecurity>yes</WindowsSecurity><UserName /><Password /></SQL><NTService ID="{6ABAD351-9C7B-423e-9FDE-3A5C52441C00}" DisplayName="Rule Engine Update Service" Description="Notification for the deployment/ undeployment of policies"><UserName>.\Stephen</UserName><Domain /><Password></Password></NTService></Feature></Configuration>
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0509 Info Configuration Framework]Configuring feature: WMI
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0522  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CBtsCfg::ConfigureFeature
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0530  Info BtsCfg]     Configuring feature: WMI
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0537  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CBtsCfg::IsSelectedAnswer
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0544  Info BtsCfg] Leaving function: CBtsCfg::IsSelectedAnswer
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0552  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::Connect
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0572  Info BtsCfg] Leaving function: CWMI::Connect
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0582  Info ConfigHelper]   NT group BizTalk Server Operators was not created because it already exists
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0589  Info ConfigHelper NetAPI Info: ] The specified local group already exists.
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0598  Info ConfigHelper]   NT group BizTalk Server B2B Operators was not created because it already exists
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0621  Info ConfigHelper NetAPI Info: ] The specified local group already exists.
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0635  Info ConfigHelper]   NT group BizTalk Server Administrators was not created because it already exists
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0645  Info ConfigHelper NetAPI Info: ] The specified local group already exists.
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0659  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::CreateGroup
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0778  Error BtsCfg] d:\bt\52584\private\source\setup\btscfg\btswmi.cpp(436): FAILED hr = c0c02402

[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0786  Error BtsCfg] An internal failure occurred for unknown reasons.
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0792  Error BtsCfg] d:\bt\52584\private\source\setup\btscfg\btscfg.cpp(1801): FAILED hr = c0c02402

[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0799  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CBtsCfg::UnConfigureFeature
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0806  Info BtsCfg]     Unconfiguring feature: WMI
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0812  Warning BtsCfg] BTS management server or DB names are not found in the registry.
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0819  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::StopHostInstance
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0831  Error BtsCfg] d:\bt\52584\private\source\setup\btscfg\btswmi.cpp(1551): FAILED hr = c0c02402

[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0838  Error BtsCfg] An internal failure occurred for unknown reasons.
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0845  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::UnMapHost
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0855  Error BtsCfg] d:\bt\52584\private\source\setup\btscfg\btswmi.cpp(1696): FAILED hr = c0c02402

[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0862  Error BtsCfg] An internal failure occurred for unknown reasons.
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0869  Info BtsCfg] Instantiating IBTSMsgBoxPerformance object
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0884  Info BtsCfg] Calling IBTSMsgBoxPerformance::UninstallArtifacts
Exception in CounterManager.UninstallArtifacts when uninstalling the perf counter instances. The exception details are: 
Source of exception: System
Message: Cannot delete Performance Category because this category is not registered or is a system category.
Stack trace:    at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(String categoryName)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.MsgBoxPerfCounters.MgmtDbAccessEntity.UninstallInstances(Boolean regularUninstall)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.MsgBoxPerfCounters.CounterManager.UninstallArtifacts(Boolean regularUninstall, String logFileName)
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0906  Info BtsCfg] Stopping Tracing
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0912  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::DeleteServer
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0922  Error BtsCfg] d:\bt\52584\private\source\setup\btscfg\btswmi.cpp(1351): FAILED hr = c0c02402

[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0929  Error BtsCfg] An internal failure occurred for unknown reasons.
[2018-07-18 20:34:46:0936  Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::UnConfigureGroup
[2018-07-18 20:34:56:0948  Info BtsCfg] Leaving function: CBtsCfg::UnConfigureFeature
[2018-07-18 20:34:56:0956  Info BtsCfg] Leaving function: CBtsCfg::ConfigureFeature
[2018-07-18 20:34:56:0963 Warning Configuration Framework]Feature failed to configure: WMI.
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0056 Info Configuration Framework]Configuration Summaries:
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0078 Error Configuration Framework]Feature: [Group] Failed to configure with error message [An internal failure occurred for unknown reasons.]
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0090 Error Configuration Framework]Feature: [BizTalk Runtime] Failed to configure with error message [Feature is skipped due to dependent feature (Group) failed to configure correctly.]
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0101 Error Configuration Framework]Feature: [BAM Tools] Failed to configure with error message [Feature is skipped due to dependent feature (Group) failed to configure correctly.]
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0110 Info Configuration Framework] Feature: SSOServer,Engine   Configuration Enabled: yes  Sub UI: no  Configured: yes
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0117 Info Configuration Framework] Feature: SSOServer,Engine   Configuration Enabled: no   Sub UI: yes Configured: yes
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0123 Info Configuration Framework] Feature: WMI    Configuration Enabled: yes  Sub UI: no  Configured: no
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0130 Info Configuration Framework] Feature: Engine,BTSCfg  Configuration Enabled: no   Sub UI: no  Configured: no
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0137 Info Configuration Framework] Feature: RulesEngine    Configuration Enabled: yes  Sub UI: no  Configured: yes
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0143 Info Configuration Framework] Feature: MOT    Configuration Enabled: yes  Sub UI: no  Configured: no
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0150 Info Configuration Framework] Feature: BAMTools   Configuration Enabled: no   Sub UI: no  Configured: no
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0156 Info Configuration Framework] Feature: BAMTools   Configuration Enabled: no   Sub UI: yes Configured: no
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0162 Info Configuration Framework] Feature: MsEDIAS2   Configuration Enabled: no   Sub UI: no  Configured: no
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0169 Info Configuration Framework]Leaving function ConfigureFeatures().
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0176 Info Configuration Framework]Entering function WizardStep_NextStepChanged.
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0188 Info Configuration Framework]Entering function ConfigWizardResult_Load.
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0210 Info Configuration Framework]Leaving function ConfigWizardResult_Load.
[2018-07-18 20:34:57:0239 Info Configuration Framework]Leaving function WizardStep_NextStepChanged.
```

Comment: Are you posting the correct log? This log seems to be some errors during rollback of the installation and not during installation itself?

Comment: Yea it's the correct log...I can't post it all because it is too large but I did add more to the top of it to show that it was installing before that unknown error occurred.

Comment: I found this particular post, which indicates it may have to do with Group Policies: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/635641e2-d17a-4b3c-9edb-4488e4fa4ae7/biztalk-server-2013-group-configuration-failing?forum=biztalkgeneral

Comment: I'm not seeing much in the way of what group policy to change.  I went ahead and just used an Azure BizTalk VM and was up and running quickly.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue after doing a clean install on an environment having the latest MS patches.
After making sure neither DTC nor other knowns issues exist, had to dig deeper.

What made the configuration wizard succeed was to edit the BTSWMISchema.mof found in \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2016\Bins32\

Look at the post from Colin Dijkgraaf at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d08c395-1550-4171-8c03-23e1d2a9afbc/microsoft-security-updates-cause-biztalk-admin-console-errors-an-internal-failure-occurred-for?forum=biztalkgeneral
where he describes the steps to edit and recompile the mof file.

Reboot the server and run configuration.exe again.

This is probably not "by-the-book-method" but it worked for us.